# Custom SQL query with ORDER BY matching condition in Symfony

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have struggled for hours to make the following query work but I only receive "null" as result. What I want is to order the selected entries by the condition they have matched. For example, first name: Anthony, last name: Anderson have 'a' char in both his last and first name but I want him to be on top of the list beacuse his first name, but not last. Here is what I have so far but as I said the only result is an array(null,null,null...)

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();                           

$rsm->addEntityResult(Lover::class, 'l');                
$rsm->addFieldResult('l','first_name','firstName');      
$rsm->addFieldResult('l','last_name','lastName');        
$rsm->addFieldResult('l','nickname','nickname');         

$result = $em->createNativeQuery("                       
    SELECT * FROM lover AS l                             
    WHERE l.first_name LIKE :search                      
        OR l.last_name LIKE :search                      
        OR l.nickname LIKE :search                       
    AND l.id != :id                                      
    ORDER BY CASE                                        
        WHEN l.first_name LIKE :search THEN 1            
        WHEN l.last_name LIKE :search THEN 2             
        WHEN l.nickname LIKE :search THEN 3              
    END                                                  
    ", $rsm)                                                 
       ->setParameter('search', "$term%")                       
       ->setParameter('id', $this->getUser()->getId())          
       ->getArrayResult();
```

Where 'lover' is the name of my table in my database. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add some more sample results.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using a NativeQuery (and ResultSetMapping) for this?

Comment: Bob Anderson, Andrea Boka, Anthony Peres, Nevy Orthon will order to Andrea Boka, Anthony Peres, Bob Anderson without Nevy Orthon for keyword 'A'. What I want is to order users by their first names, last names and finally nicknames but peoples whose first name contains the keyword will be in front of those whose last name, but not first, contains the searched character.  Respectively the one whose nickname only contains the keyword will be at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've missed adding the id parameter to the ResultSetMapping object. Now it works as expected.